# Ignore DTD warning in textmate2 XML validation

Tags: textmate2

I'm using textmate2 for editing my XML files. Sometimes I want to validate the correctness of the XML. The bundle "XML" offers the syntax validation. However, it gives me the following error: "validity error: Validation failed: no DTD found !".

Now my question: can I set it up to ignore those warnings?

Comment: Looks like the command runs xmllint, have you tried modifying the call in `Bundles` -> `Bundle Editor` -> `XML`->`Menu Actions`-> `Validate Syntax`?  Im not sure exactly what to change though

Comment: Thanks GrahamPHeath, will try to change it. I wasn't aware that it runs xmllint at the background.

Comment: You could also ask the [TextMate mailing list](http://lists.macromates.com/listinfo/textmate). Alan the developer is incredibly helpful.